# run() with multiple catch statement

Tags: java, exception

I had a run() call as below. As soon as I add another catch block below the SQLException one I see error stating `This method must return a result of type Boolean`
Is there an issue with the type of exception I am trying to catch that can cause this issue, because I am returning a boolean. No code change in that part.
The point is that in the second catch block I only log without rethrowing anything.

```
.run(
            () -> {
              try () {
               /* a lot other code */
                return booleanValue;
              } 
              catch (SQLException e) {
              // throws another exception
              }

            }
);
```

Comment: You must specify what to return in the event that you catch an exception. By the way, `return booleanValue;` cannot possible throw an SQLException.

Comment: In the existing SQLException catch block, I see we don't specify anything explicitly. We only throw a new exception. How is that working if I need to mention in the new catch block what should be returned.

Comment: The method either needs to return a value, or end exceptionally. So what happens in your second catch block ( you should include it in your problem!). If you don't throw another exception, then you need to return a value.

Comment: Understood, I only logged and hence the error. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, we don't know your "run" signature. So this question lacks a lot of details. What it look like is you have.

```
interface Something{
    boolean doStuff();
}
```

Then you have a method.

```
void run( Something s ){ ...}
```

So you can call run with a lambda that must implement the `Something` interface.

```
public boolean doStuff(){
    try{
        boolean result = exceptionalStuf();
        return result;
    } catch( SqlException e){
        //doesn't need to return, it terminates exceptionally.
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch(Exception e2){
        //needs to return or re-throw.
        return false;
    }

}
```